# Port Greasemonkey script to Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, port, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have found a Greasemonkey script which works fine in Firefox but not in Chrome, which is my preferred browser.
http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/105578

I have tried to fix it myself but without luck.
I have posted [my findings during debugging, here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/issues/105578).

How do I fix it?

---

**Update:** (from OP comment)

> Got it working by contacting the developer of TamperMonkey. With the
>   newest beta of TamperMonkey and a modification of the script it works.
>   See [this thread at userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org/topics/84252).
>
> **An additional issue noted:** It seems that Chrome forbids the direct
>   access to the anchor's `href` attribute (in some cases).
>
> However if the `href` attribute is retrieved via `getAttribute()`
>   everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome does not support the `GM_` functions natively, and that script makes heavy use of cross-domain `GM_xmlhttpRequest()`.

The smartest thing to do is to install [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo), which can *probably* run the existing script as is.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=18857#c111
According to this, GM_xmlhttpRequest() should work. I use Chrome 13.0.782.109 beta.

By using Tampermonkey the GM_ functions seems to works, as it does not complain about not beeing connected to icheckmovies anymore.
But the script still does not work.

Comment: OK, they just released cross-site XHR capability, which means that GM_xmlhttpRequest() *should* work outside of Tampermonkey.  But you're going to have to be a lot more specific than "the script still does not work". Break it down to chunks. –

Comment: After this line the output of the variable ns is not the same in FF and Chrome.
ns.push(r.snapshotItem (i));

Firefox: ns=/movie/alien/ 
Chrome: ns=

In reality the difference is that Firefox colors the [C] orange, then green and on icheckmovies.com the movie is checked.
In Chrome a [C] is only colored orange and then nothing more happens.

Comment: Got it working by contacting the developer of TamperMonkey. With the newest beta of TamperMonkey and a modification of the script it works.
http://userscripts.org/topics/84252

Comment: Excellent.  Refreshing initiative, too.